# not empty or != null not working for sets in JSTL

Tags: jstl

I have a object with a method returning sets but empty set is not evaluated with "not empty".

```
${not empty object.AdjSet}
```

this value is shown as true

Is there any other way to evaluate a set is empty or not. Same happening for != null condition.

Answer (score 1):

You have tried without object?

```
<c:if test="${not empty AdjSet}">
```

an alternative is

```
<c:if test="${AdjSet ne null}">
```

Comment: Hey!! thanks, but can u tell me how does it evaluate that without the object.

Comment: Usually I passed the object in the tag form, or in the controller of the view.

Comment: I did not get you. How did it get that "AdjSet" is from object ?

Comment: the object is passed to view with model attribute